# Xamarin - Rivets Component - DeepLink when the app is not started

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Rivets Components to create a deep link android application.
I am able to deeplink to the application when i have app running in the background. However when the app is not started it throws exception.

My code is derived from the rivets samples (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/rivets) My code looks as under:

```
[Activity (Label = "ProductActivity")]
    [IntentFilter(new [] {Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        DataScheme= "mobisaveqaapp", //new[] {"mobisaveqaapp","mobisavedev"},
        DataHost="*",
        Categories=new [] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class ProductActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ProductLayout);

            var id = "No Product ID Found";

            if (Intent.HasExtra ("al_applink_data")) {

                var appLinkData = Intent.GetStringExtra ("al_applink_data");

                var alUrl = new Rivets.AppLinkUrl (Intent.Data.ToString (), appLinkData);

                /*Todo: fetch Applinkdata target url,
                 * replace double slash with single slash,
                 * find the word offers,
                 * fecth the next index,
                 * start main activity,
                 * open all deals,
                 * open deal push async*/


                var offersVM = new OfferViewModel();
                var tableItems = offersVM.OfferCategories;
                Deal Localdeal = new Deal();

                foreach (var categories in tableItems)
                    if (categories.Key == "All Offers") {
                        Localdeal.DealName = categories.Key;
                        Localdeal.DealCount = categories.Value;
                        break;
                    }

                var url ="http://test:7070/nvtest/offers/664"; 

                url = url.Replace (":", "/");
                url = url.Replace ("//", "/");
                string[] words = url.Split('/');

                for(int i = 0;i<words.Length;i++) {
                    if (words [i].Trim ().ToLower () == "offers" && words [i + 1] != null) {
                        id = words [i + 1];
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                            if(App.Current != null && App.Current.MainPage != null && App.Current.MainPage.Navigation != null && App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.ToList ().Count > 0)
                            {
                                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new OffersSlideView(Localdeal, Convert.ToInt32(id)),false);  

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPageNew());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            }

            this.Finish();


        }
    }
```

Ill need help on how to start the deep linked application. Do let me know if i am wrong anywhere or if this question is unclear.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you told us the exact exception that is being thrown, and which line is causing it

Comment: Hi Jason,the exception is : "cannot perform action after onsaveinstancestate" . The else part fails. Else part executes when the app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override OnSavedInstance on your MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
   //Yes, comment or delete the next line:
   //base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```